# Dealing with curly braces in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, lua

I'm trying to generate a table with bolded text using a Lua snippet. Here's a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l|l}
    \begin{luacode}
      array = {1, 2, 3}
      for value in next, array do
          tex.sprint("\\textbf{", value, "} ", "& ", value*2, "\\\\")
          tex.print(" ")
      end
    \end{luacode}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However LuaLatex fails to compile, with the following error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<template> \unskip \hfil }
              \hskip \tabcolsep \hskip -.5\arrayrulewidth \vrule width\arrayru
l.14     \end{luacode}
```

I am new to LuaLatex, so it's not entirely clear to me what's happening here. One possibility is that the `&` or the `\` are being parsed first by the TeX compiler rather than the Lua compiler.
Is there any way to avoid that happening and making Lua insert the string fragments in the TeX source code as they are?

Comment: you started an environment `\begin{luacode}` so you can not have `&` before the end of the enviroment.

Comment: In that case, how does one align the entries of the table withing the `luacode` environment?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the bigger problem is that `\begin...\end{luacode}` wraps the content in a group.

Comment: You'll probably have better luck using `luacode*` and `sprint`ing the `begin`/`end` `tabular`s from inside. You can likely use `pgfplotstable` instead, which shouldn't need _any_ Lua.

Comment: @HenriMenke sure, that's another way of saying the same thing "environment" being top level synax for a group. I never find `luacode` that useful and would simply use `\directlua` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You can not start an environment in one cell and end it in another, so (as is often the case) `\begin{luacode}` isn't helping here. Your Lua code works fine though:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l|l}
    \directlua{
      array = {1, 2, 3}
      for value in next, array do
          tex.sprint("\string\\textbf{", value, "} ", "& ", value*2, "\string\\\string\\")
          tex.print(" ")
      end
    }
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```